# Oracle specifying join order hint

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle-11g-r2

Oracle 2 node RAC 11G R2

I have a query (this is a simplified version, but still exhibits the same issue as the larger query) that looks like this:

```
SELECT
   t1.trip_id,
   t1.origin,
   t2.sighting_date
FROM trips t1
JOIN trip_details t2 on t1.trip_id = t2.trip_id
WHERE 
--don't the get the information if the trip *only* belongs to customerid 99
99 <> any(select customerid from customer_trip ct where ct.trip_id = t1.trip_id);
```

- `trip` has trip level information - `trip_id`, `origin`, `destination`, etc
- `trip_details` has sightings for the trips - `trip_id`, `sighting_date`, `sighting_location`, etc
- `customer_trip` has which trips belong to which customers - some trips may be shared between customers and some may not,  so the basic structure is just `customer_id`, `trip_id`

The problem is that it keeps joining `trip` and `trip_details` first, and then limiting by the `99<> any..` statement.  The `99 <> any..` statement greatly reduces the rows from `trip` and would reduce the rows looked up in `trip_details` (which is very, very large - 100x `trip`).  So, ideally, I'd like it join trips and the customertrip subquery first, and then do trip_details.

But I can't figure out if there's a way to specify a join order such that it does it in that order.  The `LEADING` hint doesn't seem to have a way to reference the subquery.

Stats are all up to date.

Comment: The optimiser internally will translate the `all(...)` part into `NOT EXISTS ()`. Just a comment while I ponder ;) See http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql.php

Comment: @Phil - should be ANY(...) but still same issue

Comment: Well, changing to an `exists()` works actually...may want to put an answer.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7225/17

Comment: Can you show us the explain plan for the query, along with any index in place please?